# Concatenate data in sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table1

```
     Pre    Ba          pre-Ba       kgs    fl
    6L34    1523726 6L34-1523726    0.01    Bm1
    6L34    1523726 6L34-1523726    0.04    Bm1
    6L34    1523726 6L34-1523726    0.06    Bm1
    BM51    13K732  BM51-13K732      0      Bm1
    BM51    13K732  BM51-13K732      8      Bm1
```

table 2

```
 Pre    Ba          pre-Ba       kgs    fl
6L34    1523726 6L34-1523726    0.01    Bm2
BM51    13K732  BM51-13K732     0.02    Bm2
BM51    13K732  BM51-13K732        8    Bm2
```

I'm trying to combine these query tables as one by union all , but concatenate "fl" col with condition eg: in table 1 **pre-Ba** col data  ***6L34-1523726*** has 0.01 kgs is matching with table2 data  ***6L34-1523726*** with 0.01 kgs so the result should like

```
Pre      Ba         pre-Ba       kgs    fl
6L34    1523726 6L34-1523726    0.01    Bm1&bm2
6L34    1523726 6L34-1523726    0.04    Bm1
6L34    1523726 6L34-1523726    0.06    Bm1
BM51    13K732  BM51-13K732     0       Bm1
BM51    13K732  BM51-13K732     8       Bm1
6L34    1523726 6L34-1523726    0.01    Bm2&bm1
BM51    13K732  BM51-13K732     0.02    Bm2
BM51    13K732  BM51-13K732     8       Bm2&bm1
```

How do i specify that in a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would do this with a FULL OUTER JOIN. But... that doesn't exist in Access. So you'll need to to do two queries, utilizing LEFT OUTER JOINs and some logic to insure no overlap:

```
SELECT
    t1.pre,
    t1.ba,
    t1.pre-ba,
    t1.kgs,
    t1.f1 & "&" & t2.f1
FROM
    table1 as t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 as t2 ON
        t1.pre = t2.pre AND
        t1.ba = t2.ba AND
        t1.pre-ba = t2.pre-ba AND
        t1.kgs = t2.kgs

UNION ALL

SELECT
    t2.pre,
    t2.ba,
    t2.pre-ba,
    t2.kgs,
    t2.f2 & "&" & t1.f2
FROM
    table2 as t2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 as t1 ON
        t2.pre = t1.pre AND
        t2.ba = t1.ba AND
        t2.pre-ba = t1.pre-ba AND
        t2.kgs = t1.kgs
```

The first query gets everything that is in Table1, but not in Table2 as well as stuff that's in Table1 AND Table2. The second query gets things that are only in Table2.

Comment: It gives me only one occurrence when kgs match,  like **0.01  Bm1&bm2** but need to have 2 occurrences like in result shown in question

Comment: Gotcha. I was considering that a duplicate. I have removed the WHERE condition in the second query which should allow that to flow through.